# Android Error while merging dex archives

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After updating my android studio and build tool version get this error.I have tried all the solution available for this problem over internet ,  but not successful 
don't know why this is happening ??

> Android studio version: 3.1
>
> Gradle version": 4.4
>
> Gradle plugin : 3.1

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

My build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.abc"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true //Tryed this but not worked
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases'
        }
//    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/michelelacorte/maven/" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    configurations {
        all*.exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.0'
    // multipart entity
    implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.+') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }
    implementation 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
    //    implementation 'com.wonderkiln:camerakit:0.13.0'
    implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    implementation 'org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:1.9.0'
    //    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    //    compile 'com.android.support:support-emoji:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0-native'
    implementation 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'
    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.2.0'
    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-experimental:4.2.0'
    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.2.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.0.4'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.eyalbira.loadingdots:loading-dots:1.0.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    // implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.1'
    //    compile 'it.michelelacorte.swipeablecard:library:2.3.0@aar'{
    //        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    //        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    //    }
    // BUTTER KNIFE
    implementation('com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1') {
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    //    implementation project(':libemoji')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.0'
}
```

It's waste almost my 10 days...
most confusing error ever encounter..

Comment: did you clean and  rebuilt your app ?

Comment: @vikassingh 100 times

Comment: Below versionName just add this `multiDexEnabled true` and try to clean project and run

Comment: @AmjadKhan same error

Comment: multidex isn't a problem here. 
when you reach over 64k methods you would get a different error signature when not using `multiDexEnabled true` . This error seems to be conflicting usage of same library and different version in one of the gradle dependency.

Comment: Post the entire on here.

Comment: Your issue is probably with this dependency:   ```implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.+') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }``` I had an aar module that added this dependency, and couldn't build in my main project. When I removed this, I was able to build.

Comment: Even i am getting the same error! Please help if you got the solution for the same.

Comment: It's 2023 and I'm getting this error. Is there a known fix for this? I am in process on upgrading the RN app and can run gradlew assemble in debug mode perfectly, but getting this error when assembling in release mode.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens if your code has two different **modules** of `google-play-services` or `support-v4` which are using different **versions** of these libraries. 
Check the dependencies of the libraries you are using in your project or use

```
gradle app:dependencies
```

to see dependency tree of your project and then when you find out which libraries is used with different version, add it to your dependencies with correct version. For example if `google-play-services:location:11.2.0` appeared in your dependencies, replace it with `google-play-services:location:11.8.0`

Usually you will see a warning or error message in your `build.gradle` file (i.e. one dependency will be marked with red underline showing it cause version mismatch) in such cases.

Comment: Even better to check dependencies issue in web console: ./gradlew app:dependencies --scan

Answer (score 0):

In my case, project and module's package name is same. When running in debug mode, everything is okey. But when i want to build release mode. I got this error. Renaming package name is the solution for me.